# Audio input to Raspberry Pi

Tags: usb, hardware, audio, input-device

Can I use 3.5mm jack to USB converter in order to connect a headset to my Raspberry Pi 2. I want to use headset with microphone as input device. When headset is connected to 3.5 mm audio jack it can be used as output device only. I don't wish to use USB webcam with Mic and speaker. The headset which I have has microphone but it isn't a USB headset. So I wanted to know if audio jack to USB   converter will work or not for the same.

Comment: Some of them work, some of them don't. There's a list of 'confirmed working' devices [here](http://elinux.org/RPi_VerifiedPeripherals#USB_Sound_Cards).

Answer (score 1):

No the 3.5mm jack cannot be used for input it is output only. If you need input you will need either a [USB](https://www.adafruit.com/products/1475?gclid=CjwKEAiApOq2BRDoo8SVjZHV7TkSJABLe2iDFaSPtwLx16nx5tT_andLpgCY_uElnetSxT2EyqAj7RoC1tDw_wcB) or [GPIO](https://www.adafruit.com/products/1761) soundcard with a mic input, or a USB microphone.